# CodeIgniter giving 500 Internal Error just on 1 page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I uploaded my site on live. All website is working perfectly but 1 page is showing me `500 Internal Server Error`.

Can you tell me why?

This is my controller.

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Game extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        if (!$this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')) {
            redirect('admin/login');
        }

        $this->load->model('game_model', 'game');
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->load->helper('url');

        $data['categories'] = $this->game->get_categories();

        $this->load->view('admin/includes/header');
        $this->load->view('admin/game_view', $data);
        $this->load->view('admin/includes/footer');
    }

    public function ajax_list() {
        $list = $this->game->get_datatables();

        $data = array();
        $no = $_POST['start'];
        foreach ($list as $game) {
            $no++;
            $row = array();
            $row[] = $game->title;
            $row[] = $this->game->get_category_name_by_id($game->category_id);
            $row[] = $game->rating;
            if ($game->status == '0') {
                $row[] = '<span class="label label-danger">Inactive</span>';
            } else if ($game->status == '1') {
                $row[] = '<span class="label label-success">Active</span>';
            }
            //add html for action
            $row[] = '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Edit" onclick="edit_game(' . "'" . $game->id . "'" . ')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Hapus" onclick="delete_game(' . "'" . $game->id . "'" . ')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete</a>';

            $data[] = $row;
        }

        $output = array(
            "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
            "recordsTotal" => $this->game->count_all(),
            "recordsFiltered" => $this->game->count_filtered(),
            "data" => $data,
            );
        //output to json format
        echo json_encode($output);
    }

    public function ajax_edit($id) {
        $data = $this->game->get_by_id($id);
        echo json_encode($data);
    }

    public function ajax_add() {
        $this->_validate();

        $config['upload_path']          = './assets/game_images/';
        $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|png|jpg|jpeg';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if ($this->upload->do_upload('image')) {
            $file = $this->upload->data();
            $file_name = $file['file_name'];

            if ($file_name == '') {
                $data['error_string'][] = 'Please upload an image.';
                $data['status'] = FALSE;
                echo json_encode($data);
                exit();
            }
        } else {
            $data['inputerror'][] = 'image';
            $data['error_string'][] = strip_tags($this->upload->display_errors());
            $data['status'] = FALSE;
            echo json_encode($data);
            exit();
        }

        $data = array(
            'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
            'iframe' => $this->input->post('iframe'),
            'status' => $this->input->post('status'),
            'category_id' => $this->input->post('category_id'),
            'rating' => $this->input->post('rating'),
            'image' => $file_name
            );
        $insert = $this->game->save($data);
        echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
    }

    public function ajax_update() {
        $this->_validate();

        if ($_FILES['image']['name']!=''){

            $config['upload_path']          = './assets/game_images/';
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|png|jpg|jpeg';

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('image')){
                $data['inputerror'][] = 'image';
                $data['error_string'][] = strip_tags($this->upload->display_errors());
                $data['status'] = FALSE;
                echo json_encode($data);
                exit();
            }
            else {
                $this->game->delete_image_by_id($this->input->post('id'));
                $file = $this->upload->data();
                $file_name = $file['file_name'];
            }
        } else {
            $file_name='';
        }

        if ($file_name==''){
            $data = array(
                'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
                'iframe' => $this->input->post('iframe'),
                'status' => $this->input->post('status'),
                'rating' => $this->input->post('rating'),
                'category_id' => $this->input->post('category_id')
                );
        } else {
            $data = array(
                'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
                'iframe' => $this->input->post('iframe'),
                'status' => $this->input->post('status'),
                'category_id' => $this->input->post('category_id'),
                'rating' => $this->input->post('rating'),
                'image' => $file_name
                );
        }

        $this->game->update(array('id' => $this->input->post('id')), $data);
        echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
    }

    public function ajax_delete($id) {
        $this->game->delete_by_id($id);
        echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
    }

    private function _validate() {
        $data = array();
        $data['error_string'] = array();
        $data['inputerror'] = array();
        $data['status'] = TRUE;

        if ($this->input->post('title') == '') {
            $data['inputerror'][] = 'title';
            $data['error_string'][] = 'Game Title is required';
            $data['status'] = FALSE;
        }

        if ($this->input->post('iframe') == '') {
            $data['inputerror'][] = 'iframe';
            $data['error_string'][] = 'Game Iframe is required';
            $data['status'] = FALSE;
        }

        if ($this->input->post('status') == '') {
            $data['inputerror'][] = 'status';
            $data['error_string'][] = 'Status is required';
            $data['status'] = FALSE;
        }

        if ($this->input->post('rating') == '') {
            $data['inputerror'][] = 'rating';
            $data['error_string'][] = 'Rating is required';
            $data['status'] = FALSE;
        }

        if ($this->input->post('category_id') == '') {
            $data['inputerror'][] = 'category_id';
            $data['error_string'][] = 'Please select category';
            $data['status'] = FALSE;
        }

        if ($data['status'] === FALSE) {
            echo json_encode($data);
            exit();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please tell us the error message. If you don't see any you have to [enable error messages](http://stackoverflow.com/a/845025/595304).

Comment: I set the environment to production and I see a blank page. No errors.

Comment: set `TRUE` for `db_debug` in database.php file and chk the DB errors

Comment: It is already TRUE.

Comment: The page is working perfectly on localhost. Just not on live.

Comment: ok and extension is?? what `dbdriver` are u using ?

Comment: mysqli on both live and local

Comment: Sounds like a BOM character, probably at the very start of the document. Make absolutely sure that `<?php` has no characters  (possibly invisible) before it.

Comment: There is absolutely no character before it.

Comment: one last test, if you are using CI3 than your class name must start from capital letter Game.php

Comment: Go check the server’s error log.

Comment: Yes I checked it. The error is in this line. <?php echo form_upload(['name' => 'image', 'id' => 'image']); ?>

Comment: It doesn't support short array tags I suppose

Comment: than did u tried `<?php echo form_upload(array('name' => 'image', 'id' => 'image')); ?>` ??

Comment: Yes i tried and it worked. Thankyou you all. I was looking in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using short array tag in your code for production.

```
<?php echo form_upload(['name' => 'image', 'id' => 'image']); ?>
```

You just need to use like simply:

```
<?php echo form_upload(array('name' => 'image', 'id' => 'image')); ?>
```

Your PHP version is not allowed you to use php short tag array.

---

**Update:**

> *Adding comment of @Simba:* You need to upgrade
>   your php version urgently -- short array format has been around since
>   PHP 5.4. If your php doesn't support it, then it means you're on a
>   very old and unsupported version. You need to upgrade to avoid
>   security issues. Being able to use modern php features like short
>   array format will be a bonus, but the security worries of running an
>   old version should be more important.

Comment: @ali-zia: i have updated, this will help to future visitors

Comment: If this is true, then you need to upgrade your php version urgently -- short array format has been around since PHP 5.4. If your php doesn't support it, then it means you're on a very old and unsupported version. You need to upgrade to avoid security issues. Being able to use modern php features like short array format will be a bonus, but the security worries of running an old version should be more important.